# Record streaming video from samba server on linux

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, samba, streaming

I have a Samba server running which is hosting a video file. The video file is working with VLC player on my PC as well as MX player on Android. Now I want to record the video from the terminal without simply downloading it. 
I have tried the following

```
sudo cvlc smb://<Samba Server IP>/path/to/video.mp4
```

This plays the video from terminal. Therefore I know it's streamable

However, I just can't get it to record the video from the terminal.

I've tried this command by consulting the VLC documentation https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Receive_and_Save_a_Stream/

```
sudo cvlc smb://<Samba Server IP>/path/to/video.mp4 --sout=file/ps:output.mp4
```

This simply downloads the video instead of streaming it

I've also tried this command (using ts instead of ps)

```
sudo cvlc smb://<Samba Server IP>/path/to/video.mp4 --sout=file/ts:output.mp4
```

This one results in a corrupt video file.

*How should I record the video in such a way so that the video is recorded while being streamed?*

Note: I don't want to use RTP/RTSP as it has some issues with my testbed

Answer (score 0):

You need to set two destinations `display` and a file.
**Example:**
`sudo cvlc smb://<Samba Server IP>/path/to/video.mp4 --sout "#duplicate{dst=file{dst=output.mp4,no-overwrite},dst=display}"`

**Tip:**
You can use vlc's GUI to get the configuration for `sout`, it will be shown in the step "Option Setup" for the stream configuration like this:

[image: Example]

[For more information](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/display/)